# How do I find number of submissions of a url in digg?

Tags: php, api, digg

API documentation in Digg is totally confusing...does any one know how to count submissions for a particular URL in PHP??

some API paths that will return in XML or Json will do...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It looks like the number of diggs is included in the events tag in the response.